# You are not authorized to view this page

Tags: security, iis

I had websites in on my server and I stored them in path D:websites...
and When I changed the websites to new path D:websites\Pages...
this error apear when browse thes websites

You are not authorized to view this page

please any one help me.

Comment: Check the logs for additional information??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that file permissions are allowing read operations for the IIS user (assuming you are using anonymous access).